# Sublime Text 3 : Creating Snippet using simple regex

Tags: regex, code-snippets, sublimetext-snippet

I tried to create a simple snippet that check if there is a 's' and print me the result

```
${1:s} ${1/(^s$)/(?1yes:no)/}
```

When there is only an s it should print me `"s yes"`
else it should simply print me for example `"notAnS no"`

What it actually does is printing me `"notAns notAnS"`
It works well when there is an s

I feel the `(?1foo:bar)` does not work properly, I read that from
https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html

Comment: The solution to your problem is to use `${1:s} ${1/(^s$)|(.*)/(?1yes:)(?2:no)/}` though offhand I don't know the subtleties of why that doesn't work the way the documentation says, which could be because of a newer boost version or based on how in a variable substitution like this it runs for every character and not the value as a whole like you might expect.

Comment: @OdatNurd It definitely works, Thank you !